# how will i take future months by the given month and year in php

Tags: php, datetime, monthcalendar

```
 INSERT:<input type="text" name="my">
    no of months:<input type="text" name="noofmonths">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
```

Ater clicking the submitting button i want the corresponding future month/year.

```
Eg:INSERT: Septemeber 2015;
no of months:4;

i want an o/p:January 2016;
```

another eg:

```
Eg:INSERT: December 2015;
no of months:2;

i want an o/p:February 2016;
```

Comment: Seems a nice project. Tell us if you find any error when trying to implement it so we can help you!

Comment: I don't know the sql query for inserting.

Comment: Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

Suppose user enter this date

```
$date = "20 September";  //Your spelling for September is wrong make sure user enter correct spelling
```

User enter 4 in months

```
echo $effectiveDate = date('F Y', strtotime("+4 months", strtotime($date)));
```